# Laravel - resourceful controller does not show 404 for unknown methods

Tags: php, laravel-4

I created a resourceful controller via artisan . Its works fine all index create and update, delete. But I try to access unknown methods in that resource controller but it calls index method. Actually I need to show 404 for undeclared methods  because its is an unknown route. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: post your routes code or we cant help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in docs, you can handle the `404` error easilly. to read more about error handling, refer to this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors)

Docs state that to controll that event, simply add :

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```